# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working for UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I'm using UITableViewAutomaticDimension for adjusting the cell height which has a dynamic label and an image.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0;
```

I want to resize the cell as the content of the label increases and it is working perfectly.

I want to keep a minimum height for the cell(say 80) for the image to fit in always even if the label has no content at all. I've applied autolayout and set constant height, width, top space and leading space constraints to the imageview. But the cell height is going lower than the constraint height when the label content is less.

What should I do to make the cells to keep a minimum height to fit the imageView while using the 'UITableViewAutomaticDimension' feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check constrains of your layout for UITableViewAutomaticDimension work it need top constraints and bottom also if cell contains both constrains of any of cell subview it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create an assistant hidden view, which set its top、bottom constraint to the contentView of cell, any width and x position, and then set its height **Greater Than or Equal** to 80.

Comment: Then I'm getting the 'inequality constraint ambiguity' error

Comment: Yes. This solution is working. I replaced the hieght constraint '=' with '>=' and its the key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add ratio contraint

```
[self.tableview setNeedsLayout];

[self.tableview layoutIfNeeded];

[self.tableview reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

add ratio contraint and put the code where you want reload tableview

```
- (void)refreshWithData:(NSArray *)synopsissarr atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    synopsisArray=synopsissarr;

    [self.tableview setNeedsLayout];

    [self.tableview layoutIfNeeded];

    [self.tableview reloadData];
```

Answer (score -1):

highsun16 is right.  I would have liked a bit more detail.  Here's a demo project that provides all the detail necessary to replicate highsun16's answer:

[image]

Comment: One more thing, the Label's _number of lines_ needs to be 0.

Comment: please post answer like the reader can understand easy even if he/she is new in this.